# marginal pdf of multiple variables

Tags: probability

given 
$$
f_{u,v}(u,v)=4e^{-2(v+\frac{v}{u})} \frac{v}{u^2}
$$
give the marginal pdf of $U$ how do I do this? I know how to get a marginal CDF, but, a marginal pdf? I have tried splitting the function into two functions:

$$
f_{v}(v)=4e^{-4v} \\ 
f_u(u)=e^{\frac{1}{u}}\frac{1}{u^2}
$$
but this is incorrect, the book states $\frac{1}{(u+1)^2}$ asthe correct answer,  but how?
any tips ar e welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marginal pdf of $f(x, y)$ with respect to a variable is simply $f(x, y)$ integrated over the other variable's domain. In other words, you have:
$$
f_{u}(u) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(u, v)\,dv=\frac{4}{u^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}ve^{-2(1+\frac{1}{u})v}\,dv
$$
Now you can either just do the integral by parts, or we can use the fact that the expected value of an exponential distribution $f(x) = \theta e^{-\theta x}$ is $1/\theta$, and thus:
$$
f_{u}(u) =\frac{4}{2u^2(1+\frac{1}{u})}\int_{0}^{\infty}2(1+\frac{1}{u})ve^{-2(1+\frac{1}{u})v}\,dv= \frac{4}{2u^2(1+\frac{1}{u})}E\left[\text{exp}\left(\theta=2(1+u^{-1})\right)\right] \\
=\left(\frac{4}{2u^2(1+\frac{1}{u})}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2(1+\frac{1}{u})} \right)=\frac{1}{u^2(1+\frac{1}{u})^2}=\frac{1}{(u+1)^2}
$$